# GDAL library missing error

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-rest-framework, gdal

I am trying to run a Django application (new to Django development). When I try to run it, it gives me an error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried resolving it by installing GDAL python library, pointing `gdal.h` c library and `gdal.dll` file but the the error still persists.

This is the description of the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000021343D46378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
from .features import DatabaseFeatures
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .fields import (  # NOQA
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .collections import (  # NOQA
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, LinearGeometryMixin
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis import gdal
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

*versions of both python and dll*
[bit verstion of both python and the dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmqWx.png)

Comment: On Windows, a "The specified module could not be found" message can also mean the program (i.e. `python.exe`) is 64-bit (x64) and the DLL is 32-bit (x86), or vice versa.

Comment: Seems like both Python and DLL are 64 bit. I added an image for reference, hoping if it can give more details.
Also I'm passing the path like  <code>GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r"C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal202.dll"</code>  Isn't it the correct way to pass a path in python.

Comment: You can check which version of GDAL is searched by using the ProcessMonitor to be sure that the searched version match the installed one and you could also see where the search fails.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Thanks Max and AKX. It's the version problem and got it resolved :)